# After update to java7u25 from java7u21 jax-ws client of my program throws Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding

Tags: security, netbeans, jax-ws, java-7

I have the software based on jax-ws services that was built in NetBeans. Software uses Standard Encription "Username Authentication with Symmetric key", and algorithm site: Basic 128. Everything built like standard netbeans Sample "Secured Calculator", but with one difference: My client is standalone swing application.

Prior java7 update 25 everything worked fine but after update i got exception printed below. By the way, to reproduce exception you don't need server side of jax-ws, it appeared in the client part before connecting to the server side.

**Exception:**

```
algorithm is not supported for key encryption java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
```

**The link to the source code:**
To run the source code you need netbeans 7.3, jdk7u25, tomcat7(if you run server part) and don't forget to correct path to the certificates in the certs folder included in the archive.

**To download source:** please go to the link below and select file menu after select download, you will download archive delCl.zip. it consists three folders

1. delCl: client part
2. delServ: server part
3. certs: certificates

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bxah0w_hE4JZTy16YUZGREgzN2s/edit?usp=sharing

***Please Help to fix that !!!***

**Full Exception text:**

```
[com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyConfigParser]  parse
INFO: WSP5018: Loaded WSIT configuration from file: file:/C:/TeachProjects/delCl/build/classes/META-INF/wsit-client.xml.
черв 20, 2013 8:00:25 AM com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.CryptoProcessor getCipherValueOfEK
SEVERE: WSS1904: Unable to compute Cipher Value / decrypt key as http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p algorithm is not supported for key encryption
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:524)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.CryptoProcessor.initCipher(CryptoProcessor.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.CryptoProcessor.getCipherValueOfEK(CryptoProcessor.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.JAXBEncryptedKey.getCipherValue(JAXBEncryptedKey.java:274)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.keyinfo.SymmetricTokenBuilder.process(SymmetricTokenBuilder.java:255)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.TokenProcessor.process(TokenProcessor.java:190)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.SignatureProcessor.sign(SignatureProcessor.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.sign(SignatureFilter.java:631)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.process(SignatureFilter.java:589)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processWSSPolicy(HarnessUtil.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processDeep(HarnessUtil.java:272)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.processMessagePolicy(SecurityAnnotator.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.secureMessage(SecurityAnnotator.java:150)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.secureOutboundMessage(SecurityTubeBase.java:397)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientRequestPacket(SecurityClientTube.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:240)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:319)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:157)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:140)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.getSystemVersion(Unknown Source)
    at delcl.DelCl.getSystemVersion(DelCl.java:23)
    at delcl.DelCl.main(DelCl.java:17)

черв 20, 2013 8:00:25 AM com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.SignatureProcessor sign
SEVERE: WSS1701: Sign operation failed.
com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.CryptoProcessor.getCipherValueOfEK(CryptoProcessor.java:172)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.JAXBEncryptedKey.getCipherValue(JAXBEncryptedKey.java:274)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.keyinfo.SymmetricTokenBuilder.process(SymmetricTokenBuilder.java:255)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.TokenProcessor.process(TokenProcessor.java:190)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.SignatureProcessor.sign(SignatureProcessor.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.sign(SignatureFilter.java:631)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.process(SignatureFilter.java:589)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processWSSPolicy(HarnessUtil.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processDeep(HarnessUtil.java:272)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.processMessagePolicy(SecurityAnnotator.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.secureMessage(SecurityAnnotator.java:150)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.secureOutboundMessage(SecurityTubeBase.java:397)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientRequestPacket(SecurityClientTube.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:240)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:319)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:157)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:140)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.getSystemVersion(Unknown Source)
    at delcl.DelCl.getSystemVersion(DelCl.java:23)
    at delcl.DelCl.main(DelCl.java:17)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:524)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.CryptoProcessor.initCipher(CryptoProcessor.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.CryptoProcessor.getCipherValueOfEK(CryptoProcessor.java:166)
    ... 25 more

черв 20, 2013 8:00:25 AM com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase secureOutboundMessage
SEVERE: WSSTUBE0024: Error in Securing Outbound Message.
com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.SignatureProcessor.sign(SignatureProcessor.java:140)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.sign(SignatureFilter.java:631)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.process(SignatureFilter.java:589)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processWSSPolicy(HarnessUtil.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processDeep(HarnessUtil.java:272)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.processMessagePolicy(SecurityAnnotator.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.secureMessage(SecurityAnnotator.java:150)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.secureOutboundMessage(SecurityTubeBase.java:397)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientRequestPacket(SecurityClientTube.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:240)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:319)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:157)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:140)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.getSystemVersion(Unknown Source)
    at delcl.DelCl.getSystemVersion(DelCl.java:23)
    at delcl.DelCl.main(DelCl.java:17)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.CryptoProcessor.getCipherValueOfEK(CryptoProcessor.java:172)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.JAXBEncryptedKey.getCipherValue(JAXBEncryptedKey.java:274)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.keyinfo.SymmetricTokenBuilder.process(SymmetricTokenBuilder.java:255)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.TokenProcessor.process(TokenProcessor.java:190)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.SignatureProcessor.sign(SignatureProcessor.java:109)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:524)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.CryptoProcessor.initCipher(CryptoProcessor.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.CryptoProcessor.getCipherValueOfEK(CryptoProcessor.java:166)
    ... 25 more

черв 20, 2013 8:00:25 AM com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube processClientRequestPacket
SEVERE: WSSTUBE0024: Error in Securing Outbound Message.
com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurableSoapMessage.newSOAPFaultException(SecurableSoapMessage.java:336)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.secureOutboundMessage(SecurityTubeBase.java:402)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientRequestPacket(SecurityClientTube.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:240)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:319)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:157)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:140)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.getSystemVersion(Unknown Source)
    at delcl.DelCl.getSystemVersion(DelCl.java:23)
    at delcl.DelCl.main(DelCl.java:17)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.SignatureProcessor.sign(SignatureProcessor.java:140)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.sign(SignatureFilter.java:631)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.process(SignatureFilter.java:589)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processWSSPolicy(HarnessUtil.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processDeep(HarnessUtil.java:272)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.processMessagePolicy(SecurityAnnotator.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.secureMessage(SecurityAnnotator.java:150)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.secureOutboundMessage(SecurityTubeBase.java:397)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.CryptoProcessor.getCipherValueOfEK(CryptoProcessor.java:172)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.JAXBEncryptedKey.getCipherValue(JAXBEncryptedKey.java:274)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.keyinfo.SymmetricTokenBuilder.process(SymmetricTokenBuilder.java:255)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.TokenProcessor.process(TokenProcessor.java:190)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.SignatureProcessor.sign(SignatureProcessor.java:109)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:524)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.CryptoProcessor.initCipher(CryptoProcessor.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.CryptoProcessor.getCipherValueOfEK(CryptoProcessor.java:166)
    ... 25 more

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: WSSTUBE0024: Error in Securing Outbound Message.
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientRequestPacket(SecurityClientTube.java:316)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:240)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:319)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:157)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:140)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.getSystemVersion(Unknown Source)
    at delcl.DelCl.getSystemVersion(DelCl.java:23)
    at delcl.DelCl.main(DelCl.java:17)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.getSOAPFaultException(SecurityTubeBase.java:674)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurableSoapMessage.newSOAPFaultException(SecurableSoapMessage.java:336)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.secureOutboundMessage(SecurityTubeBase.java:402)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientRequestPacket(SecurityClientTube.java:311)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.SignatureProcessor.sign(SignatureProcessor.java:140)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.sign(SignatureFilter.java:631)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.process(SignatureFilter.java:589)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processWSSPolicy(HarnessUtil.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processDeep(HarnessUtil.java:272)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.processMessagePolicy(SecurityAnnotator.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.secureMessage(SecurityAnnotator.java:150)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.secureOutboundMessage(SecurityTubeBase.java:397)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.CryptoProcessor.getCipherValueOfEK(CryptoProcessor.java:172)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.JAXBEncryptedKey.getCipherValue(JAXBEncryptedKey.java:274)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.keyinfo.SymmetricTokenBuilder.process(SymmetricTokenBuilder.java:255)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.TokenProcessor.process(TokenProcessor.java:190)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.SignatureProcessor.sign(SignatureProcessor.java:109)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:524)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.CryptoProcessor.initCipher(CryptoProcessor.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.enc.CryptoProcessor.getCipherValueOfEK(CryptoProcessor.java:166)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uh. Finally, I have found solution. Oracle really excluded RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding algorithm from available Cipher algorithm in java 7 update 25. It's a standard algorithm that wsit uses for securing jax-ws web services with symmetric key. 
How to solve this issue ? 
At first you have to download BouncyCastle Provider (third party provider that support required algorithm) and add it in classpath in the server and client side. In the client side also install new provider in the application just add line:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

On the server side you can add new security  provider by modify file 
JAVA_HOME\lib\security\java.security. You have to add following line:

> security.provider.11=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

11 - number of provider in loading order.

Restart your server and client. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed in jdk 1.7.45.
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8017173